# How can I know if ASP.NET core is installed in Linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In windows, it's quite straightforward by looking in the registry for the key inside `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET`.

How can I be sure a Linux machine also has it installed?

Comment: What's the goal? Obvs if you try to run a core webapp and it doesn't work that's a hint. If you're trying to automate, then details helps determine the answer...

Comment: I need to know it as a prerequisite demand in our product's installer.. it has to be installed for it to work properly.

Comment: One of the huge benefits of .NET Core is that you can deploy self-contained. Since Core apps only include what they need, you can effectively package up all the Core framework bits along with the app itself, without incurring some sort of crazy file size penalty. Instead of forcing .NET Core to be installed on the end-user machine, you should deploy self-contained.

Comment: However be aware with self contained apps you own all the servicing. If there's a security patch it won't touch self contained apps, you need to retarget, recompile and redeploy.

Answer (score 3):

This will let you know if its installed or not, if this fails.

```
dotnet --version
```

You can also define a path export `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet`

Comment: This command is for dot.net, not **ASP.NET**, they are two different components...

Comment: asp.net core, is based on core.

please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

and is based on above is already installed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: didn't work for me. `dotnet --info` worked though